# Android.view.InflateException problem

Tags: android, xml, view

I've an app where my view is inflated from xml. It worked fine before i tried to add a Horizontal slidebar, this component extends progressBar. I've added the progress bar code to my src folder in the correct package and declared it in my layout file within a relative layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="fill">
    <com.tecmark.TouchView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <com.tecmark.HorizontalSlider android:id="@+id/slider" 
        android:indeterminateOnly="false" 
        android:progressDrawable="@android:drawable/progress_horizontal" 
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@android:drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal"
        android:minHeight="30dip" android:maxHeight="30dip" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My view's constructor includes the version that passes AttributeSet that is needed to inflate from xml.

```
public class TouchView extends View
{
    private File tempFile;
    private byte[] imageArray;
    private Bitmap bgr;
    private Bitmap bm;
    private Bitmap whitebm;
    private Paint pTouch;
    private int centreX = 1;
    private int centreY = 1;
    private int radius = 50;
    private HorizontalSlider slider;

    private static final String TAG = "*********TouchView";

    public TouchView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        // TouchView(context, null);
    }

    public TouchView(Context context, AttributeSet attr)
    {
        super(context, attr);

        Log.e(TAG, "******inside touchview constructor ");
        slider = (HorizontalSlider) this.findViewById(R.id.slider);
        Log.e(TAG, "******slider inflated*********** ");
        slider.setOnProgressChangeListener(changeListener);

        // ......get bitmap and process it code
    }// end of touchView constructor

    public void findCirclePixels()
    {
        // ..... changePixel code
    }// end of changePixel()

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
    {
        // ...... event code
        return true;
    }// end of onTouchEvent

    private OnProgressChangeListener changeListener = new OnProgressChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(View v, int progress)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setProgress(progress);
        }

        private void setProgress(int progress)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "******slidebar clicked*********** ");
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawBitmap(whitebm, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bgr, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawCircle(centreX, centreY, radius, pTouch);
    }// end of onDraw
}
```

.

```
05-13 16:01:17.911: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tecmark/com.tecmark.Jjilapp}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.tecmark.TouchView
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.tecmark.TouchView
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433):     at com.tecmark.Jjilapp.onCreate(Jjilapp.java:30)
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433):     ... 11 more
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433):     at com.tecmark.TouchView.<init>(TouchView.java:59)
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433):     ... 21 more
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-13 16:01:17.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2433):     ... 25 more
```

.

Has anyone any ides why i'm getting this exception? Thanks matt.

Comment: What line / file is the NullPointerException at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
slider = (HorizontalSlider) this.findViewById(R.id.slider);
```

initialized inside your `TouchView` class' code, which I doubt to be correct, since the `slider` is **not inside** the `TouchView`, though it's inside the `Activity`, in the same layout the `TouchView` is.

You could remove the code from the `TouchView`'s constructor, and put it inside a method `public initSlider(HorizontalSlider slider)`.

Then in your `Activity`'s `onCreate` method, you access both the `TouchView` and the `HorizontalSlider` views as

```
//TODO add id to your TouchView in xml!
final TouchView touchView = (TouchView)findViewById(R.id.touchView); 
final HorizontalSlider touchView = (HorizontalSlider)findViewById(R.id.slider); 

touchView.initSlider(slider);
```

And your `TouchView`'s constructor will be splitted:

```
public TouchView(Context context, AttributeSet attr)
{
    super(context, attr);
    Log.e(TAG, "******inside touchview constructor ");
    // ......get bitmap and process it code
}// end of touchView constructor

public void initSlider(final HorizontalSlider slider)
{
    Log.e(TAG, "******setting up slider*********** ");
    slider.setOnProgressChangeListener(changeListener);
}
```

Comment: hey thanks alot, it works perfectly. Thanks for taking the time to recode it

Answer (score -1):

You're accessing your `HorizontalSlider` view from within the `TouchView` constructor. That HorizontalView hasn't even been instantiated yet. Even if it had been, it's likely not going to be located by a `findViewByid()` from the `TouchView` since it's not a child of the `TouchView`. I think you need to rethink your logic a bit.